What is the motivation behind the library obfuscation change in AGP 8.4?
I've read that Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) 8.4 introduces a change where libraries are obfuscated, and the obfuscated classes are included in the consumer builds. I understand the general benefits of obfuscation, such as increased security and reduced risk of reverse engineering. However, I'm specifically interested in the reasons and motivations behind this change being introduced in AGP 8.4.Can someone explain why the AGP team decided to implement this change now, considering that the final APK is already obfuscated? What specific issues or improvements are they addressing with this update?
Context: Upgraded AGP to 8.4 and release builds failed, e.g., hilt generated classes are removed by R8. When I disable minify for modules except app, the error disappears as expected.

Yeah, the new Lib Obfuscation change in AGP 8.4+ causes a lot of issue in the release build. I don't know/see any benefit yet.
